# What are the pros and cons of using OpenZeppelin ERC20Votes?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, voting

I want to use [this extension](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20Votes) for an `ERC20` token.

What are the pros and cons (if any) of adding this to it?